# Learning fragment UI in android ran into an error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android

So, I'm using the tutorials on Androids development site, and ran into this problem. On this bit of code

```
DetailFragment detailfrag=(DetailFragment).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_pane);
```

Eclipse highlights (DetailFragment) as an error and says it cannot resolve DetailFragment to a variable.

Here's the pastebin to the mainactivity code http://pastebin.com/QLWLicnh
Why does it think DetailFragment is a variable? Was the android dev lessons wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
    DetailFragment detailfrag=detailfrag(DetailFragment).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_pane);
```

Because you have a period and no space after (DetailFragment).  Hence you aren't trying to cast to DetailFragment, but call some method on DetailFragment.

Use the following instead.

```
    DetailFragment detailfrag = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_pane);
```